# why the value of class member variable change?

Tags: c#, class

i have a class

```
    class ABC
    {
          public int a = 2;
          public void valueA(ABC objabc)
          {
               a = 5;
               objabc = new ABC();
               objabc.a = 11;
           }
    }
```

then i write main as

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ABC objabc = new ABC();
        objabc.a = 15;
        objabc.valueA(objabc);
        Console.WriteLine(objabc.a);
     }
```

When i execute this i found 5 in output.so my question is that why a = 5??why it is not 2, 11 or 15??

Comment: That's a strange question, is this homework?

Comment: What I dont understand is why you are creating an un-used ABC object in the valueA method to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the `valueA` method on the object `objabc`. Inside the method the member `a` of `this` is set to 5. You can see the code as equivalent to:

```
class ABC
{
      public int a = 2;
      public void valueA(ABC objabc)
      {
           this.a = 5;
           objabc = new ABC();
           objabc.a = 11;
       }
}
```

So you are setting the member of the object on which you called the method to 5. This object being `objabc` from `main`, so the final value is 5. **The fact that you are assigning it a new object reference afterwards makes no difference, because you are not passing it by reference so changes are not visible outside.**

The result would be different (i.e. 11) if your code was this:

```
class ABC
{
      public int a = 2;
      public void valueA(ref ABC objabc)
      {
           a = 5;
           objabc = new ABC();
           objabc.a = 11;
       }
}
```

In this case the parameter would be passed by reference, so the assignment `objabc = new ABC();` would be visible to the calling code (i.e. in `Main`).

Comment: Thnx tudor....your second example help me to find out the difference between first one and second one..thnx..

Answer (score 0):

First you create an instance of `ABC`. This will set the value of `a` to 2. Then you set the value of `a` to 15 using the field directly. Then you call a method which sets the very same field to 5 and then it creates *another* instance in which you set the value of its version of `a` to 11. This other instance doesn't affect the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ABC objabc = new ABC(); // Value of a is 2
    objabc.a = 15; // Set it to 15
    objabc.valueA(objabc); // This resets it to 5, then creates a new object and sets it to 11
    Console.WriteLine(objabc.a); // You're still calling a on the old object, not the new one
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A class is a reference type. 
When you pass as a parameter "ABC objabc", your method creates a new objabc. It goes away when you exit the method because you don't return anything. 
So, you can:
- Return your object and then print this object, returned by your method or;
public ABC valueA(ABC objabc); 
- Pass the keyword "ref" before your objabc, to keep the reference to your class created before (IE: public void valueA(ref ABC objabc).

But it don't make many sense, pass the class object to the same class.

Good luck!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx